# running a batch file using xsl and fop....Problems with the fop

Tags: xslt, batch-file, apache-fop

I am running my simple little batch program:

```
@echo off

transform data_files\sql_dump data_files\sql_to_xml transformed_files\sql_dump_to_xml
transform transformed_files\sql_dump_to_xml data_files\convert_to_html_amt transformed_files\converted_to_html_amount html
transform transformed_files\sql_dump_to_xml data_files\convert_to_html_date transformed_files\converted_to_html_date html
transform transformed_files\sql_dump_to_xml data_files\convert_to_html_sperson transformed_files\converted_to_html_salesperson html
transform transformed_files\sql_dump_to_xml data_files\convert_to_fo transformed_files\converted_to_fo fo
fop transformed_files\converted_to_fo.fo transformed_files\converted.png
fop transformed_files\converted_to_fo.fo transformed_files\converted.pdf
fop transformed_files\converted_to_fo.fo transformed_files\converted.rtf
```

For some reason, all expected files show up, save for the last two. Why would that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In windows, FOP is a BAT file and not an EXE file.

To invoke it from a batch file, you should

1. either use `CALL FOP` or
2. as an alternative you can run `java -jar path/to/fop/fop.jar`, relying on FOP to build the classpath for running FOP dynamically.

Read `HELP CALL` and read FOP documentation.